# Is it possible to run the Omnet++ with a command in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, omnet++

Hello I am new to the Omnet++. I was trying to run the Omnet from the Matlab. Is it possible to run the particular project and generate results in Omnet++ using the Matlab or any command and without actually going on the graphical interface for pressing run button in Omnet++?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read in the official documentation site (https://omnetpp.org/), it is a library for discrete event simulation. The library is writeen in C++.

It is possible to compile and use C++ code and results using the Matlab MEX-API. (http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html). This API provides a fairly easy bidirectional connection interface between Matlab and C++. It enables matlab to create data to be further processed in C++ and the show the results on matlab later.

Hope it is useful for you!

Comment: Thank you for you support. I will try your suggestion.