Does anybody have any idea how to use MATLAB Engine API directly from Omnet++?
I am trying to run a simulation in Omnet++ which is very easily simulated in MATLAB so now i want to somehow call his from OMNET++ and I read somewhere that it is possible by using Engine API in MATLAB but i cant find any documentation regarding that.
i have tried including library paths from MATLAB in omnet++ and still there are alot of errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255345/is-it-possible-to-run-the-omnet-with-a-command-in-matlab does this answer your question?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
